# How do you architect a requirement to arrive at the efforts?

Tags: architecture

I would like to know how do experienced Architects estimate efforts with an RFP to help  work out the development cost of a system, which will help us to give a meaningful proposal.

In the same lines, i would also like to know how do we decide on a development team, provided we know the rough man hours, to be more precise, how do we decide on number of team lead, Sr. developers, Jr. Developers etc.

I understand these are all very subjective questions, i just need some abstract directions on how do experts do these things, and in the process make the project a sucess.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time!!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most valuable things we do is keep accurate records of previous projects, then using some kind of size estimation tool (function points etc) you can compare the proposed project with an historical one and try to estimate that way.

Experience helps as does quite a lot of luck!